# finding parent in rails polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on implementing polymorphic comments (these can be applied to just about any user content on the site, and is not limited to `Article` instances. When creating a comment, I need to determine which `commentable` it belongs to. Most of the writing I have found on this subject suggests that I use the pattern specified in `find_commentable` in the code below, but this approach does not strike me as very elegant - it would seem there should be a straightforward way to unambiguously specify the `commentable` a new comment is being created for, without traversing the `params` set, and without string matching. Is there a better way?

In other words, is there a better way to access the `commentable` object from the `comment` controller in the context of a `commentable` → `comment` association? Does it still work the `create` method where we do not yet have a `@comment` object to work with?

My models are set up as follows:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, dependent: :destroy
end

class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
  def create
    @commentable = find_commentable  
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build(comment_params)

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to :back
    else  
      render :action => 'new'
    end  
  end

  def index
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comments = @commentable.comments
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end

    def find_commentable
      params.each do |name, value|
        if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
          return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can redefine your find_commentable method: `params[:commentable_type].constantize.find_by_id(params[:commentable_id]])`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was looking for an answer to this as well and wanted to share  [**Launch Academy's Article on Polymorphic Associations**](http://www.launchacademy.com/codecabulary/learn-rails/polymorphic-associations) as I felt it provided the most succinct explanation.
For your application two additional options:

**1. The "Ryan Bates" Method:** (when you use Rails' traditional RESTful URLs)

```
def find_commentable
    resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
    @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
end
```

**2. The Nested Resource:**

```
def find_commentable
    commentable = []
    params.each do |name, value|
      if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
        commentable.push($1.classify.constantize.find(value))
      end
    end
    return commentable[0], commentable[1] if commentable.length > 1
    return commentable[0], nil if commentable.length == 1
    nil
end
```

**3. The Single Resource:** (Your implementation but repeated for completion)

```
def find_commentable
  params.each do |name, value|
    if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
      return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I would do it the other way round - make the comment then define commentable.

```
@comment = Comment.create(params[:comment]) #this is the standard controller code for create
@commentable = @comment.commentable
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer. This method does not appear to associate the newly created comment with any specific `commentable`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I assumed you were doing that via the params.

Answer (score 1):

I took Ryan Bates idea and tweaked it a bit.  I have some deeper scoped and nested resources.

```
id, resource = request.path.split('/').reverse[1,2]
@commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.friendly.find(id)
```

The idea here is that you are stripping off the parent from the end of the path.

So if your path is `/scope/resource_a/1234/resource_b/5678/comments` etc. no matter how deep you nest that you always get the top level parent.